# Pass line id as argument in x-editable or TbEditableColumn to update a particular record

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to use TbEditableColumn / X-Editable to make inline edits in the CGridView. I'm trying to use the usual $data variable to get row id by the intuitive "$data->id" to pass the line id in the dynamically generated url so that in the update action of the controller, I'd know which record to update.

However $data->id is just not working while creating URL. Interestingly the same $data variable is accessible while applying "Editable" property on the item. See below.

I don't want to go for JS:function way to fetch id of an element and pass it as argument in ajax call. This just doesn't seem elegant.

```
                array(
                            'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
                            'name' => 'mrp',
                            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:200px'),
                            'editable' => array(
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'apply' => '$data->id>10605',
                                    'url' => '/product/changeMRP/id/$data->id',
                            ),
                    ),
```

In above code, this line works

```
'apply' => '$data->id>10605'
```

But this line doesn't

```
'url' => '/product/changeMRP/id/$data->id',
```

Why is it that? And how can i solve my problem?

I followed this question : 
[How can update db values using x-editable EditableColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881032/how-can-update-db-values-using-x-editable-editablecolumn) but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createUrl()` for creating `URL` and pass the `id` in `array`. Like this

```
'url' => "Yii::app()->createUrl('product/changeMRP', array('id'=>'$data->id'))",
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried that ... but that too is not working. It is creating a "bad url" .. something like this http://localhost/product/changeMRP/%24data/-%3id .. apparently it is not parsing as php variable.