# Update database using TbEditableColumn YiiBooster

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, yii-booster

I'm working with Yii and YiiBooster, I'm using `TbEditableColumn` to edit my `GridView`.

Is it possible to change data in my table using this editable column?

This is my code:

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'id' => 'post-grid',
'type' => 'striped bordered',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    array('name' => 'author_name', 'value' => '$data->author ? $data->author->username: "-"'),
    array('name' => 'kegiatan', 'value' => 'str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\n", $data->kegiatan)'),
    'pic',
    'keterangan',
    'create_time',
    array(
            'class' => 'booster.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
            'name' => 'feedback',
            'sortable' => false,
            'editable' => array(
                'url' => $this->createUrl('updateFeedback'),
                'placement' => 'right',
                'inputclass' => 'span3'
            )
        ),
    array(
        'header' =>'Action',
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

What must I do in MyController/updateFeedback?

Comment: the answer is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881032/how-can-update-db-values-using-x-editable-editablecolumn